# Sceen freezes very often in Ubuntu 18.04 but mouse moves, keyboard input works (Ctrl+Alt+F1 to log in again works)

Tags: 18.04, freeze

I researched this problem here and on Google but didn't come up with a solution this far.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 and have a massive problem with random screen freezes. I can't pinpoint it to any program but it seems to appear more often when using Firefox for browsing, but in general, it can appear when I do nothing on the desktop. The screen freezes but I can move the mouse pointer (it also changes appearance for hyperlinks and stuff like that) but the screen doesn't refresh. Audio will play on (for instance while watching a movie). I can login again using Ctrl+Alt+F1 but sometimes it takes only seconds until the screen freezes again.

Here some random logs that might help, if you need more info, let me know. Any help is appreciated!

*free -h*

```
              Gesamt   belegt    frei        gemns. Puffer/Cache verfügbar
Speicher:        3,8G        1,9G        173M        146M        1,7G        1,5G
Auslagerungsspeicher:        3,9G        1,0M        3,9G
```

*lspci | grep VGA*

```
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barts XT [Radeon HD 6870]
```

---

Update: I tried adding the acpi_rev_override=1 argument to splash in /etc/default/grub which didn't work. A change in the Bios graphics settings for the graphics to be "discrete" isn't existing in my Bios.

Comment: I just posted a similar but different question an hour earlier. Altho' I don't have Radeon graphics, there's links to other posts about a Radeon graphics freeze in my question, which had a solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260103/ubuntu-20-04-graphics-freezes-for-1-2-seconds-every-5-seconds

Comment: @BobBriscoe thanks for the hints, I tried adding acpi_rev_override=1 in /etc/default/grub and looked in my Bios for a "discrete" graphics option but the first didn't work and the second didn't exist. The problem is still around ...